# ERROR: return reinterpret_cast<T>(pgm_read_ptr(p));

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, web-server, esp8266webserver, dht11

I need to update **DHT** sensor data to the webserver in ***JSON*** format using **ESP8266**. This is my code.

```cpp
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <DHT.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

const char* ssid = "YOUR_SSID";
const char* password = "YOUR PASSWORD";
const int dhtPin = D4;
DHT dht(dhtPin, DHT11);
ESP8266WebServer server(80);

void handleRoot() {
  float temperature = dht.readTemperature();
  float humidity = dht.readHumidity();

  if (isnan(temperature) || isnan(humidity)) {
     server.send(500, "text/plain", "Failed to read from DHT sensor");
    return;
  }

  StaticJsonDocument<200> jsonDoc;
  jsonDoc["temperature"] = temperature;
  jsonDoc["humidity"] = humidity;

  String jsonString;
  serializeJson(jsonDoc, jsonString);

  server.send(200, "application/json", jsonString);
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi...");
  }

  Serial.println("Connected to WiFi");
  dht.begin();
  server.on("/", handleRoot);
  server.begin();
  Serial.println("Server started");
}

void loop() {
  server.handleClient();
}
```

But I got error like,

```
In file included from c:\Users\Kuralmozhi.R\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson\src/ArduinoJson/Polyfills/static_array.hpp:11:0,
                 from c:\Users\Kuralmozhi.R\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson\src/ArduinoJson/Numbers/FloatTraits.hpp:14,
                 from c:\Users\Kuralmozhi.R\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson\src/ArduinoJson/Numbers/FloatParts.hpp:8,
                 from c:\Users\Kuralmozhi.R\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson\src/ArduinoJson/Json/TextFormatter.hpp:11,
                 from c:\Users\Kuralmozhi.R\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson\src/ArduinoJson/Json/JsonSerializer.hpp:7,
                 from c:\Users\Kuralmozhi.R\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson\src/ArduinoJson/Variant/ConverterImpl.hpp:7,
                 from c:\Users\Kuralmozhi.R\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson\src/ArduinoJson.hpp:37,
                 from c:\Users\Kuralmozhi.R\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson\src/ArduinoJson.h:9,
                 from C:\Users\Kuralmozhi.R\Downloads\ID_2\ID_2.ino:5:
c:\Users\Kuralmozhi.R\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson\src/ArduinoJson/Polyfills/pgmspace_generic.hpp: In instantiation of 'typename ArduinoJson6193_F1::enable_if<ArduinoJson6193_F1::is_pointer<T>::value, T>::type ArduinoJson6193_F1::pgm_read(const void*) [with T = const __FlashStringHelper*; typename ArduinoJson6193_F1::enable_if<ArduinoJson6193_F1::is_pointer<T>::value, T>::type = const __FlashStringHelper*]':
c:\Users\Kuralmozhi.R\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson\src/ArduinoJson/Deserialization/DeserializationError.hpp:85:12:   required from here
c:\Users\Kuralmozhi.R\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson\src/ArduinoJson/Polyfills/pgmspace_generic.hpp:15:45: error: 'const void*' is not a pointer-to-object type
   return reinterpret_cast<T>(pgm_read_ptr(p));
                                             ^

exit status 1

Compilation error: exit status 1
```

I don't know how to solve this error. Please suggest me some ideas!

---

I tried to update ESP8266. But now it shows like this,

```
Variables and constants in RAM (global, static), used 28984 / 80192 bytes (36%)
║   SEGMENT  BYTES    DESCRIPTION
╠══ DATA     1504     initialized variables
╠══ RODATA   1376     constants       
╚══ BSS      26104    zeroed variables
Instruction RAM (IRAM_ATTR, ICACHE_RAM_ATTR), used 60439 / 65536 bytes (92%)
║   SEGMENT  BYTES    DESCRIPTION
╠══ ICACHE   32768    reserved space for flash instruction cache
╚══ IRAM     27671    code in IRAM    
Code in flash (default, ICACHE_FLASH_ATTR), used 273120 / 1048576 bytes (26%)
║   SEGMENT  BYTES    DESCRIPTION
╚══ IROM     273120   code in flash
```

Comment: Please copy and paste the actual error, including the line number, not something "like" the error. Edit your question to do this.

Comment: Sounds like [this problem](https://github.com/bblanchon/ArduinoJson/issues/1442).

Comment: I can't understand this problem. Can you explain briefly?

Comment: What version of the Arduino IDE are you using?

Comment: The page linked by Fahad suggested: I suggest you upgrade or reinstall the ESP8266 core for Arduino. If that's still not working, you can disable support for PROGMEM until we figure what's wrong (see ARDUINOJSON_ENABLE_PROGMEM).

Comment: What is your issue with the output after the update? In my eyes this looks like a successful build.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the info from [the link Fahad provided in the comments](https://github.com/bblanchon/ArduinoJson/issues/1442), I can only offer a guess: Your ESP8266 board definitions are outdated and the old version of the ESP8266 board definitions contains a bug.

There is an outdated URL to the ESP8266 board definition JSON floating around on the web. I *guess* you found that one. The URL still works, but is not updated anymore. Please check the version of your ESP8266 board definitions: Open the Board Manager (`Tools -> Board -> Board Manager`), search for ESP8266 and verify that the version is at least 3.1.2 (current version as of this writing; I don't know the lowest version where this bug is fixed).

If the Board Manager does not offer to update to version 3.1.2 (or later), you may need to provide the current URL to the board definitions in `File -> Preferences -> Tab "Settings" -> Additional Boards Manager URLs`. Remove the old ESP8266 URL, but don't remove URLs for *other* boards. Then try to update using the Board Manager again:

```
https://arduino.esp8266.com/stable/package_esp8266com_index.json
```

Comment: This works! Thank you so much orithena!!